# How to install avssamp and avshws drivers?

Tags: driver, wdk, wdm

I am trying to install AVstream Driver (avssamp) by following instruction in https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/avstream/avssamp. My driver shows in device manager under camera after successful installation but does not show in Sound, video and game controllers or Audio inputs and outputs. Also it does not show in graphedit too.

Does anybody have experience in installing these AVstream drivers (avshws and avssamp).

I am using WDK for Win 10, version 1803 and compiler VS2017.

Answer (score 1):

Got the solution and installed avshws, I think the drivers were not digitally signed that is why window were not registering them. Got it installed through add legacy hardware hdwwiz.exe. Now it has registered video capture device in wdm streaming capture devices.